# Create modern site team site template

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

I've created a template from the root site i.e communication site. Now when i create the site using the custom template, the site is being created as Team classic site. I actually want a site to be created as Modern Team site, What is the best way to create a modern team site based on template?

Comment: Not sure what you want. But check [this](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2019/02/05/convert-classic-root-sites-to-modern-sharepoint/) if it helps you in any way.

Comment: That link is to convert a communication site to mordern site. What am looking is that if i download the template from a team site then when i create a new site, based on that template, the new site is created as a team classic site rather than team modern site.